# Writing scripts with arguments?

Tags: bash, scripts, command-line

I want to write shell script that takes an argument, and then applies it to files.

Specifically, I want to give a term, and then have it compile term.as with mxmlc ("mxmlc term.as"), then run term.swf with flashplayerdebugger ("flashplayerdebugger term.swf"). I'm fairly new to shell scripting - any thoughts?

Comment: `$2` is the first argument, `$3` the second, and so on.  `$1` is reserved for the name of the file.  As for the other stuff, I don't quite understand what you mean.  Could you please try to explain it a little better or write some psuedocode?

Comment: @InkBlend you're off by one. `"$1"` is the first argument.

Comment: @geirha: Ouch.  That hurts.  You're right, of course.  Silly me, I must have been thinking of Python.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $0 is the script name, $1 id the first ARG, $2 is second...
NAME="$1"
mxmlc $NAME.as
flashplayerdebugger $NAME.swf
```

Comment: Or skip the `NAME` variable altogether and just use `mxmlc "$1".as` and `flashplayerdebugger "$1".swf`. (Quotes can be inside expressions.)

Comment: but what if the param contains spaces ?

Comment: You're quite right. I've edited my comment to fix this error.

Comment: @shinnra If the parameter contains spaces, then `nxmlc` and `flashplayerdebugger` will get multiple arguments instead of the intended one argument. The expansion of `NAME` needs to be double-quoted. On a side note, don't use all uppercase variable names; you risk overwriting special shell variables or environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

I also recommend you use the variable name delimiter.  So the code would look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $0 is the script name, $1 id the first ARG, $2 is second...
NAME="$1"
mxmlc ${NAME}.as
flashplayerdebugger ${NAME}.sw
```

This allows the use of the variable in any context, even inside other text.  For example:

```
NewName="myFileIs${NAME}and that is all"
```

This would expand the variable NAME which would be flanked in front by "myFileIs" and at the back with "and that is all"  The variable would expand, spaces included, inside the string.  if NAME was "inside here" the NewName would be "myFileIsinside hereand that is all".

The command line can take up to 9 variables.  They can be quoted strings which contain blanks, each quoted string counts as a variable.  Such as:

`./myProg var1 var 2 var3`

So `${1}` is `"var1"`, `${2}` is `"var"`, `${3}` is `"2"`, `${4}` is `"var3"`

BUT:
`./myProg var1 "var 2" var3`

has `${1}` is `"var1"`, `${2}` is `"var 2"`, `${3}` is `"var3"`

Have fun!