# crontab job not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

### Backgound

I am trying to run an `sh` script every minute using crontab, but it is not working.

### Problem

When I run the script manually, it executes properly, however crontab can't do it.

I created the job using `crontab -e`, and I can see cron is running because if I type `pgrep cron` I get the PID in return.

I also know that my time format is correct because I tested it [with this online tester](http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php?cron=*%20*%20*%20*%20*&iterations=10&test=Test).

### Code

**wallpaperSlider.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
feh --randomize --bg-fill /home/username/Pictures/wallpapers/*
```

**crontab job**:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * username /home/username/.crons/wallpaperSlider.sh
```

### Research

I have read the most common errors in AskUbuntu and I don't think I am experiencing any.

I understand that perhaps I am missing some environment variable, but I am not sure how to check that.

I also know that `crontab -e` changes/creates a tmp file, in my case `/tmp/crontab.wCajAu/crontab`.

### Question

1. How can I make this script execute in cron?
2. Having in mind that `crontab -e` changes a file in the `tmp` folder, will I lose all changes once I reboot?

Comment: I am following this tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: If some envvars missing it is important which desktop environment (DE) you using. In [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/911958/566421) I did a script that does a similar job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cron format is wrong. You want:

```
* * * * * /home/username/.crons/wallpaperSlider.sh
```

User's crontabs don't have a `username` field. That is only used for system-wide crontabs like `/etc/crontab`. You also don't need `SHELL=/bin/bash` since, even if your default shell isn't bash (it is `dash` on Ubuntu), your script itself has the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) so it will be run by `bash` no matter what shell cron launches.

You will probably have other issues as well though, since you're trying to run an application that communicates with the X server from cron. If so, you need to use:

```
DISPLAY=":0.0"
XAUTHORITY="/home/YOURUSERNAME/.Xauthority"
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
* * * * * /home/username/.crons/wallpaperSlider.sh
```

Comment: I have updated my question with additional info, feel free to let me know your thoughts !

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix did you try the solution I gave in my answer? And that file in tmp is just a tmp file, it will be renamed and saved when you save and close the editor window that is opened by `crontab -e`.

Comment: I just did ! It worked! I somehow have the feeling I ended up choosing the least intuitive possible solution ... how was I supposed to know I needed those specific variables? And that I needed all of them? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix you weren't :) Cron wasn't designed to run GUI stuff, so making it work with GUI is a bit complicated. Those are the main variables needed to let a process connect to your running X server.